# How to convert Character to numeric with U$

Tags: r, dplyr, char, tidyverse

I'm very new in R and I have elementary questions.

I have a tbl who contains as follows

```
 Date         Debt
<date>         <chr>
2001-12-01    1,000,000
2002-01-01    2,000,000
2002-02-01    3,000,000
```

Above, I have a piece of code that follows. I want to transform Character in numeric, but I want to add U$ before the numbers with decimals.

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
#format to U$

format_dollar <- function(values, nsmall = 2) {
  values %>%
    as.numeric() %>%
  format(nsmall = nsmall, decimal.mark = ",",big.mark = ".") %>%
    str_trim() %>%
    str_c("U$", .)
}

format_dollar(tbl) %>% print()
```

But everytime I have runned this piece of code, this is the output

```
[1] "U$NA" "R$NA" "U$NA"
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me, please

Comment: If you add `$`, it becomes character

Answer (score 3):

The `,` would make the column `character`.  By applying `as.numeric`, it would convert all of them to `NA`.  Instead, we can remove those with  `str_remove_all` and convert to `numeric` (but appending `$` as prefix will make it to `character` class)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tbl %>%
   mutate(Debt = as.numeric(str_remove_all(Debt, ',')))
```